# Django url expression variable is returning the remainder of the url

Tags: python, regex, django

In my urls.py I have a url expression where I need to get the name of the subject in the view.

```
url(r'^notebook/(?P<subject>.+?)/new/entry/$', view, name)
```

However this returns not only the subject but also the following url. IE: chemistry/new/entry How would I get it to return just chemistry?

Edit:
Perhaps there might also be an issue with my urls.py in general. It seems like it could be triggering the subject view. Here is the relevant code:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^notebook/(?P<subject>.+?)/$', views.subject, name='subject'),
    url(r'^notebook/(?P<subject>[^/]+)/new/entry/$', views.NewEntryView.as_view(), name='new_entry'),
]
```

Comment: is your url look like this `notebook/chemistry/new/entry/new/entry/` ? or your really referring to `subject` arg ?

Comment: add the related `view` code?

Comment: edited with urls. The view for both right now is simply subject = Subject.objects.all().get(name=subject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url is being intercepted by the more aggressive (albeit not greedy) pattern:

```
url(r'^notebook/(?P<subject>.+?)/$', views.subject, name='subject')
```

Note that the second pattern is a subset of this one.

You should switch the order of the url patterns so the more restricted url gets treated first by Django:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^notebook/(?P<subject>[^/]+)/new/entry/$', views.NewEntryView.as_view(), name='new_entry'),
    url(r'^notebook/(?P<subject>.+?)/$', views.subject, name='subject'),
]
```

Or change the first one to a negated character class, so slashes are not matched:

```
url(r'^notebook/(?P<subject>[^/]+)/$', views.subject, name='subject')
```

Comment: You call the pattern greedy. What might be a better way to prevent something like this in the future? -Edit noted thanks

Comment: @mei Typo, should be not greedy. Use a negated character class.